# How do I display Liferay content from the built in Documents and Media repository

Tags: repository, liferay, portlet

I've integrated Liferay and Alfresco, using Alfresco as the primary CMS and Liferay as the presentation tier.

In Liferay's control panel, I've added the Alfresco repository using the utility in Documents and Media and the folders and files stored in that repository all display just fine. The issue I am having is this - I do not see a clear process in Liferay's documentation on how to point a specific document stored in that repository to be displayed in a portlet.

I should add that I am using Liferay 6.1 CE on a 64-bit Windows environment. Any pointers would be wonderful.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to display the Alfresco content as articles on the web page or do you want them to be available for download? Mounting Alfresco to the document library only makes them available for download.

Comment: Yes, I am looking to display the Alfresco content within a portlet on the public-facing Liferay webpage. I've noticed the only repository document options in Liferay are to either Edit, Delete, or Download. Do you know of a different integration I should pursue in order to display the Alfresco content on the Liferay webpage?

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet worked with Alfresco integration (this is on my list for quite some time now) but you'll need a portlet that interfaces with Alfresco directly, similar to Liferay's "Web Content Display" portlet. (I believe that alfresco provides such a portlet)

Mounting Alfresco's repository to the document & media library will make it available for download - the "document and media display" portlet typically shows certain folders in the document library, but does not embed the html of those documents on a page.